# gitで差分が出続ける現象に困っています

Tags: git

gitで差分が出続ける現象に悩まされています。git statusすると以下のメッセージが出たので対処しようとしますが、、、

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app/hoge.php
    modified:   app/fuga.css

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

`stash`しても`commit`しても`reset`しても差分が出続けます。SourceTreeやGitHubのアプリケーションなどのGUIで操作しようとしても出続けます。

同様の現象に遭遇した方おりますでしょうか？

解決策の分かる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 3):

```
git add app/hoge.php
git add app/fuga.css
git commit -m "<your commit message>"
```

で解決しないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。

`$ git add app/hoge.php`
`warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/hoge.php.`
となったのでググってこちらの記事のとおり以下のコマンドを打ったらコミットできました。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Kmizukix/20100106/1262711140

`$ git config --global core.autoCRLF false`
`$ git add app/hoge.php`
`$ git config --global core.autoCRLF false`
`$ git add app/fuga.css`
`$ git commit -m "message"`

ありがとうございました！

Comment: 良かったです。尚、その警告についてですが、`git`は元々Linuxの開発用に書かれたツールであるためか、Windowsの改行コード`CRLF`をLinux向け(`LF`)に書き換えようとするために起きているものです。既に書かれている通り、`core.autoCRLF`を設定するのが良いですね。